# Count Similar iTems in Array

Tags: c++, c

I need to count the similar elements in an array. For example, if i have an array,
array[0,0,0,1,2,3,3].The number of 0's are 3 , no. of 1's are 1 , no. of 2's are 1 , no. of 3's are 2 in this array . I am sorry if this message has been posted before. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

THM

P.S : Language is C/C++

Comment: Is it C or C++? They are very different languages.

Comment: @Mike ok i apologize , i need it in C++.

Comment: @nOrd its not my homework i m an IT Professional working for a software house. Actually its been a long time since i have worked in C++. Theres a frnd of mine who asked me for such a code . I posted it here thinking i might get an answer quickly.

Comment: @Rich I dont wanna try , as its not my assignment. a frnd of mine asked me for such a code. And i will appreciate if i get an answer from u people.

Comment: Asking on behalf of a friend sounds particularly fishy. - Anyway do you need to count all distinct values at once, or do you have to find out, say, how many 0-s are there and never care about the other values?

Comment: Where's the option to close a question because it's *rude*?  Or do we have a `rude` tag for that?  Oh wait, the rude title was added by a moderating edit... WTH?

Comment: @Ben: I felt that I was making the title match the question, but I probably acted in haste.  Your title is better.

Comment: @Bill: The keywords you used weren't any worse than the original, but replacing "Thanks in advance" with "Give me the code" really changed the tone of the question from polite to obnoxious.  Now, the question does suffer from a lack of effort on the part of the asker, and "give me the code" appears to be *accurate* if tactless.

Comment: @Taimur: Does "it's not my homework" + "a friend of mine" mean "friend's homework"?

Comment: @Taimur: If you "don't wanna try", why should we? We're more than happy to help out by going over the logic for a problem or pointing out errors in code, but we're not just going to write the code for you if you've made no attempt yourself. Is the problem that you/your friend don't know how to approach the problem (i.e. you want to understand the logic for the algorithm), or is it just that you understand the method but don't know the specific C++ syntax/structures for writing it?

Comment: Given the requirement added below that no data structures can be used, I'd say it's a good bet it's homework.

Which is why I up-voted @stefaanv's answer to use std::map (:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few options:

1. Copy the array into a `std::multiset<>` and then use the `count()` or `equal_range()` member functions to return the counts
2. Create a `std::map<T,unsigned>`. The map key (of your array entry type `T`, which will be an integral type from your example) is the array entry, the value is the count. Increment the count associated with a value every time you encounter an element with that value as you iterate through the array
3. If the array is sorted use `std::equal_range()` to find consecutive equal elements, and count them.

There are of course many more, including just iterating though and counting directly.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a std::map to store and adapt your results based on the array-entry, while iterating over the array.  I hope this hint helps for your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I assume this is a homework then. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

How would you do if I'd ask you to implement the algorithm? You can see from your sample input that it's easier to count the members of each group when the input is grouped, rather than shuffled in arbitrary order. If you sort the input then you'll get the various elements grouped. Then you will just need to iterate over the sequence once in order to count the members of each group.

When you have the algorithm working, try to refine it such that it never reads an element of the input sequence more than once. If you can satisfy the guarantee that each element is read exactly once, and that the elements are read in order from begin to end then your algorithm will work on input coming directly from an input stream such as stdin (so long as it is coming sorted), with no need to first copy the input from the input stream to a temporary container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed reply. 
Actually its not my assignment. A frnd of mine asked me for help, 
i m an IT Professional working for a software house. Actually its been a long time since i have worked in C++. Theres a frnd of mine who asked me for such a code . I posted it here thinking i might get an answer quickly